# list.append vs pd.series.append

Tags: python, list, series

I noticed that while **list.append** changes the original list, **pd.series.append** doesn't change the original series:

```
b = [1,2,3,4,5]

b.append(9)

b

# returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9]
```

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])

s.append(pd.Series([9]))

s

# returns 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
```

Despite using Python for quite a while I never realized this and spent a long time debugging because I kept getting errors or unintended values while running a for loop for a series using the 'append' method inside. Python is my first programming language btw.

Why is there a discrepancy although both are the same methods? Or is the 'append' method an exception? It gets personally confusing because it makes a huge difference in writing python code and getting the results I want. And it makes me wonder if there are similar discrepancies for other methods between lists and series(or dataframes) as well that I should be aware of.

I'm just a bit frustrated whenever I encounter these seemingly trivial things because I personally tend to forget them later on and repeat the same mistake.

Should I just memorize this and get over with it? I wish to know the approach I should take when trying to learn new things like these because I don't know whether I'll be able to remember these kinds of subtle differences as time passes. I would appreciate any good tips or advice.

Comment: "Should I just memorize this and get over with it?" Yes. As a rule of thumb, `pandas` methods/functions by default return new objects instead of mutating existing ones. Keep in mind that `pandas` is not part of Python, it's just a very popular third party library which has its own design decisions.

Comment: The implementation is different, `Series.append()` returns a new series, `list.append()` appends to the original list.

Comment: @timgeb So what I need to know here is that pandas methods just return objects and don't alter the original series/dataframe. Is this right?

Comment: @Robin311 most of the time, unless you pass `inplace=True` (when applicable). It's just like you need to know that `list.sort()` mutates a list while `sorted` returns a new one. Some things you just have to memorize I'm afraid.

Comment: @timgeb  alright, I'll try to remember it. Good enough answer for me. Thanks!

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that "both are the same methods" is not the case. They just have the same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Pandas, the `append` method does **NOT** change the original DataFrame.

In contrast, `append` method of list changes target list.

Let's take a look.

```
b = [1,2,3,4,5]

b.append(9)

b

# returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9] # target list 'b' has been changed.
```

Case of pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'), index=['x', 'y'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=list('AB'), index=['x', 'y'])
df.append(df2)

df

# result = 
           A    B
        x  1    2
        y  3    4
```

So we have to assign clearly that we are going to change the DataFrame.
e.g.

```
df = df.append(df2) # this changes df.

df
# result =  A   B
        x   1   2
        y   3   4
        x   5   6
        y   7   8
```

Hopefully it helps :)

Comment: What does this add over the information that is already in the question?

Comment: @PastaAndBeer thanks the df2 pointer helped with this: https://pastebin.com/0XDgdUfF